# Поддерживает ли Wi-Fi адаптер TP-LINK TL-WN722N, режим монитора?

Tags: linux, wifi, adapter, kali-linux, tp-link

Поддерживает ли адаптер TP-LINK TL-WN722N режим монитора?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

tl-wn722n основан на rt2800us и изначально не предполагает режим мониторинга. Однако работать будет, если всё сделать [по инструкции](https://codeby.net/forum/threads/tp-link-tl-wn722n-monitor-mode-is-work.61101/).

1. Качаем с гитхаба новый драйвер, благодаря которому и будет работать monitor mode.

   ```
   git clone https://github.com/mfruba/kernel.git
   ```
2. Заходим в kernel/drivers/TL-WN722N_v2.0-Ralink/
3. Распаковываем обычный драйвер который находится в архиве `rtl8188eu.tar.gz` и устанавливаем его.

   ```
   tar -xvzf archive.tar.gz
   cd lwfinger-rtl8188eu-00b5f0d
   make all
   make install
   ```

   Убедитесь в том, что драйвер установился в /lib/firmware/rtlwifi/
4. Далее переходим в директорию с новым драйвером и устанавливаем его

   ```
   make
   make install
   ```
5. Устанавливаем зависимые модули

   ```
   modprobe lib80211
   modprobe cfg80211
   ```
6. Добавляем модуль в ядро

   ```
   insmod 8188eu.ko
   ```
7. Перезапускаем ОС

   ```
   shutdown -r now
   ```
8. С помощью ifconfig определяем имя интерфейса
9. И включаем monitor mode

   ```
   ifconfig [имя интерфейса] down
   iwconfig [имя интерфейса] mode monitor
   ifconfig [имя интерфейса] up
   ```

Comment: Спасибо, а не могли бы вы ответить на еще один вопрос, что лучше купить для кали линукс, TP-LINK TL-WN722N или TP-LINK TL-WN821N? Просто всегда есть риск, что инструкция не сработает, так может приобрести адаптер где эта функция поддерживается?

Comment: @Log1c0 смотрите по выдаваемой по мощности. довольно старые, но неплохие статьи: https://xakep.ru/2016/09/27/wardriving-devices/ https://losst.ru/luchshie-wifi-adaptery-dlya-kali-linux-2017. Так же где-то видел, что wn812n не принимает handshake  и не имеет мониторинга

Comment: делаю все по инструкции, но выскакивает ошибка

make[1]: *** /lib/modules/4.15.0-kali2-amd64/build: No such file or directory.
Stop.

Что делать?

Comment: @Log1c0 если вы не в силах разобраться сами, то лучше задать новый вопрос, в котором прикрепить полный вывод установки

Comment: @vp_arth благодарю) В следующий раз постараюсь вывести инструкцию, помимо ссылки)

Comment: Драйвер есть в ядре, зачем его компилировать непонятно откуда?

Comment: @0andriy если бы этот драйвер работал в monitor mode, этого вопроса не было

Comment: Ну так посмотрите глазами разницу с ванильным https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/staging/rtl8188eu/Kconfig

Comment: Ха, *lwfinger* (который выскакивает у вас при распаковке архива) как раз занимается чисткой этого драйвера в ядре. Так что более чем уверен, что там нормально всё.

Comment: @0andriy архив и драйвер не мой

Comment: Я знаю, я и не утверждал, что ваш.

Comment: @0andriy неверно прочитал, извиняюсь. Вобщем-то этот драйвер мне никогда был не нужен. У меня в ноутбуке rtl8723de

Comment: Ладно, всем спасибо у меня все получилось)